# How to achieve strictly positive forecasts?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, constrained-regression

I am working on a time series whose values are **strictly positive**. Working with various models including AR, MA, ARMA, etc, I couldn't find an easy way to achieve strictly positive forecasts.

I'm using **R** for doing my forecasts, and all that I could find was forecast.hts {hts} that has a **positive** parameter described here:

**Forecast a hierarchical or grouped time series, package hts**

```
## S3 method for class 'gts':
forecast((object, h,
  method = c("comb", "bu", "mo", "tdgsf", "tdgsa", "tdfp", "all"),
  fmethod = c("ets", "rw", "arima"), level, positive = FALSE,
    xreg = NULL, newxreg = NULL, ...))

positive
    If TRUE, forecasts are forced to be strictly positive
```

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/hts/docs/forecast.gts

Any suggestions for non-hierarchical time series? What about generalization on using other constraints like minimum, maximum, etc?

Even if not implemented in R, suggestions on articles, models or helpful general variable transformations would be appreciated.

Comment: One of the easiest, but not always correct thing to do in such case is simply forecast the log of the variable.

Comment: To partly echo @mpiktas one approach is to work on the log-scale. In practice this often improves several aspects of the model at once. While prediction intervals transform back just fine, you have to take care with mean forecasts (if normality is reasonable on the logs, you can get an estimate for the mean of the lognormal that is usually reasonable if sample sizes are large). An alternative that can sometimes work for some simple time series models is to use a Gamma model.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With the `forecast` package for R, simply set `lambda=0` when fitting a model. For example:

```
fit <- auto.arima(x, lambda=0)
forecast(fit)
```

Many of the functions in the package allow the `lambda` argument. When the `lambda` argument is specified, a Box-Cox transformation is used. The value $\lambda=0$ specifies a log transformation. So setting `lambda=0` means the logged data are modelled, and when forecasts are produced, they are back-transformed to the original space.

See http://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/4 for further discussion.

Comment: Thanks Prof. Hyndman for your kind help. I think I should reread that chapter seriously! Do you think mentioning this in chapter 2-4 can help? I think so! :-) Some questions remain for me: Can some kind of transformation be used for minimum (or maximum) possible values? I'm trying to do this with a log based function, but  after all is the resulting confidence interval mathematically correct?

Comment: Please ask the min/max question separately. Yes, the prediction intervals are correct when back-transformed.

Comment: @Ho1 Applied Time Series Analysis For Managerial Forecasting by NELSON ; Holden-Day 1973 pp162-165 discusses this in detail ... with a diverse opinion

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work as expected, as it changed the method, and instead of a nice expected y variation on predictions, it just made a flat line around the average