# Forecasting in R without auto.arima()

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am trying to forecast data regarding vehicle registrations year-wise using `auto.arima` in R. However, one of my variables (which is data for 3-wheeler registrations) gives me the same forecast: I used `auto.arima` for it too but the process generated was an ARIMA(0,0,0) process due to which the forecast values were the same throughout. For another similar variable, I got an ARIMA(0,1,0) process and my point forecasts were the same. So my question is, is there any other method of forecasting single variables without using the `auto.arima` function? Your responses and help will be much appreciated, thanking you all in anticipation!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with a constant forecast? Would you take a nonconstant one even if its accuracy were lower?

Comment: Simple models in exponential smoothing, which never change, can be the most accurate forecast.

Comment: @RichardHardy, nope, absolutely not. But the previous values of the variable weren't constant and in that case, getting a constant forecast for it just seems a bit odd.. hence I'm a bit sceptical of using these forecasts.

Comment: @user54285, which never change?

Comment: If the data generating process is a random walk or white noise, previous observations will not be constant, yet an optimal (under symmetric loss) point forecast is a constant.

Comment: @RichardHardy understood, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with a constant forecast? Would you take a nonconstant one even if its accuracy were lower? You responded, no, and I concur. Perhaps your data generating process (DGP) is best approximated by ARIMA(0,1,0) or ARIMA(0,0,0) among the class of models considered, ARIMA(p,d,q). If the DGP is a random walk, i.e. ARIMA(0,1,0), or white noise, i.e. ARIMA(0,0,0), previous observations will not be constant, yet an optimal (under symmetric loss) point forecast will be a constant.

If you were worried about possibly obtaining negative forecasts, you could refer to the thread ["How to achieve strictly positive forecasts?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80859/how-to-achieve-strictly-positive-forecasts). The core idea there is to set `lambda=0` when fitting a model with `auto.arima`: `fit <- auto.arima(x, lambda=0); forecast(fit)`. But your series values and their forecasts appear quite far away from zero, so this is probably not a problem.

If you wanted integer forecasts, Weiss ["Integer‐Valued Autoregressive Moving‐Average (INARMA) Models"](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781118445112.stat08133) (2018) could be of interest. But again, this is probably more relevant when the numbers are small, which is not the case in your example.

Comment: A simple model in exponential smoothing will be exactly the same in all future months. Basically a straight line. But in my experience its often right. The best predictor of the future is the most recent point (a simple model is not the most recent value, I think its a weighted average of recent points although I am not sure).

Comment: Thanks, @Richard. Will go with these forecasts itself:)

Comment: @user54285, thank you!